# Jquery setInterval and clearInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to highlight a list items one by one, once it reaches the final list item, highlight should be removed

setInterval is working, but when i use clearInterval to remove the Interval it doesn't work

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="anchor">I am an anchor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="anchor">I am an anchor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="anchor">I am an anchor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="anchor">I am an anchor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="anchor">I am an anchor</a></li>
</ul>


var $anchors = $('a.anchor'), counter = 0;
var interval;
interval = setInterval(function(){
 $anchors.removeClass('highlight');
  $anchors.eq(counter++ % $anchors.length).addClass('highlight');
    if($anchors.length==5){
    clearInterval(interval);
}
}, 4000);
```

anyway to clear the interval when it reaches the final list item ?

Fiddle link : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m5Mu2/89/)

Update : Sorry i was wrong in code, corrected the code, still same issue

Comment: *"Jquery setInterval and clearInterval"* `setInterval` and `clearInterval` have nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: Next time, please use Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) rather than jsFiddle, so everything in here on-site.

Comment: *"Sorry i was wrong in code, corrected the code, still same issue"* You should probably update the fiddle as well (or better yet, turn it into a Stack Snippet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If You want to highlight last one :

```js
 var $anchors = $('a.anchor'), counter = 0;
    var interval;
    interval = setInterval(function(){
      $anchors.removeClass('highlight');
      $anchors.eq(counter++ % $anchors.length).addClass('highlight');
     if($anchors.length == counter){
      clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 1000);
```

```css
.highlight{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="anchor">I am an anchor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="anchor">I am an anchor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="anchor">I am an anchor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="anchor">I am an anchor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="anchor">I am an anchor</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

If you don't wont to highlight last one

```js
var $anchors = $('a.anchor'), counter = 0;
var interval;
interval =setInterval(function(){
  $anchors.removeClass('highlight');
  if($anchors.length==counter){
   clearInterval(interval);
      return;
   }
  $anchors.eq(counter++ % $anchors.length).addClass('highlight');
   
}, 1000);
```

```css
.highlight{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="anchor">I am an anchor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="anchor">I am an anchor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="anchor">I am an anchor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="anchor">I am an anchor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="anchor">I am an anchor</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Good point to use `$anchors.length` rather than the hardcoded 5.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
var interval;
interval = setInterval(function(){
  $anchors.removeClass('highlight');
  $anchors.eq(counter++ % $anchors.length).addClass('highlight');
    if($anchors.length==5){
    clearInterval(interval);
}
}, 4000);
```

Comment: Last anchor still will be highlighted

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong condition to stop the timer. `$anchors.length` will always be 5 with what you've shown; want you want to check is `counter`.

```
var $anchors = $('a.anchor'),
    counter = 0;
var interval;
interval = setInterval(function() {
    $anchors.removeClass('highlight');
    $anchors.eq(counter++ % $anchors.length).addClass('highlight');
    if (counter == 5) {
//      ^^^^^^^-------------------------------- change is here
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 4000);
```

Live example:

```js
var $anchors = $('a.anchor'),
  counter = 0;
var interval;
interval = setInterval(function() {
  $anchors.removeClass('highlight');
  $anchors.eq(counter++ % $anchors.length).addClass('highlight');
  if (counter == 5) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 400);
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="anchor">I am an anchor</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="anchor">I am an anchor</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="anchor">I am an anchor</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="anchor">I am an anchor</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="anchor">I am an anchor</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note: xAqweRx [makes a good point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37109822/157247) in his solution that using `counter == $anchors.length` rather than `counter == 5` is more robust; that way, when you change the number of anchors, the code keeps working.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a **different** simpler way to go:

```
function stopInt(cnt, int) {
    if(cnt > $anchors.length){
        clearInterval(int);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Call this function at the end of a cycle. Also, I'm not sure how that `counter++ %` increment modulus is? I simply put the `counter++` all by itself and it looks like there's no need to extract the modulus...modulus really?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/29w0dby8/2/)

### SNIPPET

```js
var $anchors = $('a.anchor'),
  counter = 0;
var interval;
setInterval(function() {
  interval = $anchors.removeClass('highlight');
  $anchors.eq(counter).addClass('highlight');
  stopInt(counter, interval);
  counter++;
}, 4000);

function stopInt(cnt, int) {
  if (cnt > $anchors.length) {
    clearInterval(int);
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="anchor">I am an anchor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="anchor">I am an anchor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="anchor">I am an anchor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="anchor">I am an anchor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="anchor">I am an anchor</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('a.anchor')` will return a array list of 5 elements so you have to check it till 4

```
var $anchors = $('a.anchor'),
    counter = 0;
    var interval;
    var o = setInterval(function(){
     interval= $anchors.removeClass('highlight');
      var m = counter++ % $anchors.length
      $anchors.eq(m).addClass('highlight');
      console.log(m)
        if(m==4){
      clearInterval(o);
       //$anchors.removeClass('highlight'); // Uncomment this if you want to remove the highlighted class
    }

    }, 1000);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/m5Mu2/90/)